# What's wrong with this autologin configuration?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, autologin

I'm configuring TTY auto login, so I f[ollowed the official guide,](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Automatic_login_to_virtual_console) created a file named autologin.conf in /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d, containing the following lines:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/agetty --autologin XX --noclear %I 38400 linux
```

I did this for both tty1 and tty3.

Now when my system boots, I can see the bash prompt on tty1, but my autorun scripts for tty3 doesn't run at all. (The script is in ~/.bashrc, it runs if `$(tty)` equals to `/dev/tty3`)

Any ideas?

P.S If I modify getty@.service directly, adding the autologon, it works perfectly, the auto run scripts for tty3 executes.

**EDIT**

I also noticed if I press ALT + F3 manually, after switching to tty3, the script get executed as well.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread which I think is your issue. The thread is titled: [systemd: autologin to tty1 problems](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=145335), sounds like your issue.

> note: As of systemd 30, only 1 getty will be launched by default. If
>   you switch to another tty, a getty will be launched there
>   (socket-activation style). You can still force additional agetty
>   processes to start using the above methods.

I think you need to add another getty service file.